# Надо найти длительность непрерывного нахождения на станцииях

Tags: sql, oracle, pyspark

Всем привет. 
Есть таблица: ИД абонента, ИД станции, Дата события. 
Надо найти длительность непрерывного нахождения на станциях. Решаю в Oracle,  но потом перенесу решение в pySpark. 
Рассчитала длительность события, 
флаг_lead = 0, если следующее событие на той же станции, 
флаг_lag = 0, если предыдущее событие на той же станции. Если значение этих друх флагов перемножить, то, вроде, получаю нужный критерий для группировки строк.

```
select subs_id,
       base_stat_id,
       subs_act_date,
       coalesce(lead(subs_act_date, 1)over(partition by subs_id order by subs_act_date), sysdate) as end_subs_act_date,
       coalesce(lead(subs_act_date, 1)over(partition by subs_id order by subs_act_date), sysdate)  - subs_act_date as duration,
       case when lead(base_stat_id, 1)over(partition by subs_id order by subs_act_date) = base_stat_id then 0 else 1 end *
       case when lag(base_stat_id, 1)over(partition by subs_id order by subs_act_date) = base_stat_id then 0 else 1 end as bs_flag
from (
select 1 as subs_id, 1 as base_stat_id, to_date('8:40', 'hh24:mi') as subs_act_date from dual
union all select 1,1,to_date('8:55', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,1,to_date('9:20', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,2,to_date('10:00', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,1,to_date('11:15', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,2,to_date('12:00', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,2,to_date('13:50', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,2,to_date('18:50', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,1,to_date('18:55', 'hh24:mi') from dual
union all select 1,1,to_date('19:20', 'hh24:mi') from dual
)src_tab
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу придумать, как отделить данные из блоков 1 и 2. Так как между этими блоками абонент был на других станциях и объединять длительность нахождения в эти периоды нельзя.

Comment: А если между нахождениями есть перерыв, но на других станциях абонент не фиксировался, это считается непрерывным нахождением? И следует ли считать, что данные консистентны, то есть интервалы нахождения у одного абонента не могут пересекаться?

Comment: есть только начало события, следующая строка начало другого собятия, поэтому предполагается, что абонент до начала следующего собятия оставался на той же станции. Один абонент не может находится сразу на нескольких станциях

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что нужно найти (для каждого абонента): длительность каждого непрерывного нахождения по каждой станции или суммарную длительность непрерывных нахождений по каждой станции?

Comment: нужно нати длительность непрерывного нахождения на станциях. Из моего скрина надо найти сумму по полю DURATION строк 1-3, строки 4,5 останутся без изменения, сумму строк 6-8, и сумму строк 9, 10. То есть для станции 1 должно быть 3 суммы: 1 и 2 выделенные на скрине блоки и строка 5я.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто группируйте записи по факту, что текущее и предыдущее события были на одной и той же станции:

```
WITH 

-- исходные данные
src_tab AS (
  select 1 as subs_id, 1 as base_stat_id, to_date('8:40', 'hh24:mi') as subs_act_date from dual
  union all select 1,1,to_date('8:55', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,1,to_date('9:20', 'hh24:mi') from dual 
  union all select 1,2,to_date('10:00', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,1,to_date('11:15', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,2,to_date('12:00', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,2,to_date('13:50', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,2,to_date('18:50', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,1,to_date('18:55', 'hh24:mi') from dual
  union all select 1,1,to_date('19:20', 'hh24:mi') from dual
),

-- сравнение станций текущего и предыдущего событий
cte AS (
SELECT subs_id, base_stat_id, subs_act_date,
       CASE WHEN base_stat_id = LAG(base_stat_id) OVER (PARTITION BY subs_id 
                                                       ORDER BY subs_act_date)
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1 
            END AS station_changed
from src_tab
)

-- подсчёт номера группы
SELECT subs_id, base_stat_id, subs_act_date,
       SUM(station_changed) OVER (PARTITION BY subs_id 
                                  ORDER BY subs_act_date) group_number
FROM cte
```

| SUBS_ID | BASE_STAT_ID | SUBS_ACT_DATE | GROUP_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-AUG-23 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 01-AUG-23 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 01-AUG-23 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-AUG-23 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 01-AUG-23 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-AUG-23 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-AUG-23 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-AUG-23 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 01-AUG-23 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 01-AUG-23 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B4EVRpxa)

Сразу видно, что несколько событий подряд на одной и той же станции - это группы событий с номерами 1, 4 и 5.